# How to write if condition in Rails as ng-if in Angular js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am having a condition in Rails as:

```
if @user.permissions.include?('show_reports')
```

I need to check the above condition in angular pages.
How to write in ng-if condition?

For example there is a dropdown class as

```
.dropdown
  %h1 This is example
```

In all the other pages, they have written:

```
.dropdown{ng-if => ...}
```

but couldn't write for above condition. Please help.

Comment: For ng-if you need to have angular variables and condition. You can't use a rails if condition inside 'ng-if'

Comment: @Devd - I mean like user.permissions.showReports like that.. I will add code in angular. But just need how to translate from Rails to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('Controller', Controller);

    function Controller(){
       var scope = this;
       scope.has_reports = <%= @user.permissions.include?('show_reports') %>;
    }
</script>
```

And then use it like    'ng-if' => "ctrl.has_reports",

here ctrl is ng-controller